# node.js/socket.io: Refresh table on reconnect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have node.js and socket.io performing real-time updates on a DataTables table. When a row is edited, other clients see the updates to the row without refreshing.

This all works well, but I'm at a loss regarding how to **automatically refresh the table when node/socket reconnect to the server after a disconnect.**

Currently, this is what happens:

1. Go to page containing table
2. Let device sleep/disconnect from
   server
3. Power on device and see page containing table
4. socket.io reconnects to the server, but the table doesn't refresh to get the latest changes.

**How can I get socket.io to refresh the table upon reconnect to the server?** Ideally, the process would look like this:

1. Power on device
2. socket.io reconnects to server, triggers CSS "Loading..." overlay to prevent user from making changes to table
3. socket.io refreshes the table to show latest content
4. CSS "Loading..." overlay closes

Server-side script:

```
console.log('Starting the server');
var app = require('express')();
var express = require('express');
var fs = require("fs");

var server = require('https').createServer(SSL, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(100);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  /*socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  /socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });*/
});

io.set('authorization', function(handshakeData, accept) {
    console.log('io.authorization called');
    accept(null, true);
} );

var lockedRowIDs = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('io.connection called');

    socket.on('lock', function(rowID) {
        console.log('Lock event for rowID: '+rowID);
        lock(socket, rowID);
        lockedRowIDs.push(rowID);
    } );

    socket.on('clientJoin', function(username) {
        console.log('clientJoin event received');
        socket.join('clients');
        if (typeof lockedRowIDs !== 'undefined' && lockedRowIDs.length > 0) {
            socket.emit('lockedRows', lockedRowIDs);
        }
    } );

    socket.on('unlock', function(rowID) {
        console.log('Unlock event for rowID: '+rowID);
        unlock(socket, rowID);
        removeItemFromArray(lockedRowIDs, rowID);
    } );

    socket.on('updateData', function(json, action, id) {
        if (action == "edit" || action == "create") {
            console.log('updateData event for rowID: '+json.row['DT_RowId']);
        }
        updateData(socket, json, action, id);
    } );
} );

function lock(socket, rowID) {
    socket.broadcast.to('clients').emit('lock', rowID);
    setTimeout(function() {
        io.sockets.in('clients').emit('timeout', rowID);
        removeItemFromArray(lockedRowIDs, rowID);
    },
    180000);
}

function unlock(socket, rowID) {
    socket.broadcast.to('clients').emit('unlock', rowID);
}

function removeItemFromArray(array, item) {
    console.log('removeItemFromArray called with item: '+item);
    for(var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(array[i] === item) {
            array.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}

function updateData(socket, json, action, id) {
    if (action == "edit" || action == "create") {
        console.log('updateData called with rowID:'+json.row['DT_RowId']);
    }
    socket.broadcast.to('clients').emit('updateData', json, action, id);
}
```

Client-side script:

```
var socket = io('https://www.***.com:100');
socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    socket.emit('clientJoin');
} );

socket.on('lock', function(rowID) {
    console.log('Lock event received for rowID: '+rowID);
    row = $("tr[id='"+rowID+"']");
    row.addClass('locked');
    /* Pagenation fix Start */
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    table.row('#'+rowID).nodes().to$().addClass('locked');
    /* Pagenation fix End */
} );

socket.on('unlock', function(rowID) {
    console.log('Unlock event received for rowID: '+rowID);
    row = $("tr[id='"+rowID+"']");
    row.removeClass('locked');
    /* Pagenation fix Start */
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    table.row('#'+rowID).nodes().to$().removeClass('locked');
    /* Pagenation fix End */
} );

socket.on('timeout', function(rowID) {
    console.log('Time out event received for rowID: '+rowID);
    row = $("tr[id='"+rowID+"']");
    row.removeClass('locked');
    /* Pagenation fix Start */
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    table.row('#'+rowID).nodes().to$().removeClass('locked');
    /* Pagenation fix End */
    /* Check if the editor corresponds to the timed out rowID - start */
    var modifier = editor.modifier();
    if (modifier) {
        var data = table.row(modifier).data();
        console.log('rowID is '+data.DT_RowId);
        if (data.DT_RowId == rowID) {
            console.log('Timed out rowID: '+rowID+' matches Editor rowID: '+data.DT_RowId+'. Closing Editor now.');
            editor.close();
        }
        else {
            console.log('Timed out rowID: '+rowID+' does not match Editor rowID: '+data.DT_RowId+'. Keeping Editor open.');
        }
    }
    /* Check if the editor corresponds to the timed out rowID - end */
} );

socket.on('lockedRows', function (rowIDs) {
    console.log('Iterate through the list of rows and mark it as locked');
    table = $('#example').DataTable();
    rowCount = rowIDs.length;
    console.log('Row count: '+rowCount);
    for (var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        console.log(rowIDs[i]);
        row = $("tr[id='"+rowIDs[i]+"']");
        row.addClass('locked');
        table.row('#'+rowIDs[i]).nodes().to$().addClass('locked');
    }
} );

socket.on('updateData', function(json, action, id) {
    if (action == "create" || action == "edit") {
        var DT_RowId = json.row['DT_RowId'];
        console.log('updateData socket event for rowID: '+DT_RowId+' and action: '+action);
    }
    var table = $('table#example').DataTable();
    if (action == "edit") {
        var editedRow = table.row('#'+DT_RowId).nodes().to$();
        table.row(editedRow).data(json.row).draw();
        console.log('Row updated');
    }
    if (action == "create") {
        console.log('Row created');
        table.row.add(json.row).draw();
    }
    if (action == "remove") {
        var removedRow = table.row('#'+id).nodes().to$();
        table.row(removedRow).remove().draw();
        console.log('Row removed with id '+id);
    }
} );

/* Ajax request has been completed, data retrieved from the server */

editor.on('postSubmit', function(e,json, data, action) {
    console.log('Post submit');
    console.log(data);
    console.log('With JSON:');
    console.log(json);
    console.log('With action:');
    console.log(action);
    if (action == "create" || action== "edit") {
        if (json.row){
            console.log('rowID from JSON: '+json.row['DT_RowId']);
            socket.emit('updateData', json, action);
        }
    }
    if (action == "remove") {
        console.log('rowID from JSON: '+data.id[0]);
        socket.emit('updateData', null, action, data.id[0]);
    }
} );

editor.on('close', function(e) {
    console.log('Close event');
    console.log(e);
    var modifier = editor.modifier();
    console.log(modifier)
    if (modifier !== null) {
        console.log('Inside modifier')
        table = $('#example').DataTable();
        if (table.row(modifier).node()) {
            rowID = table.row(modifier).node().id;
            console.log('rowID='+rowID);
            row = $("tr[id='"+rowID+"']");
            row.removeClass('locked');
            table.row('#'+rowID).nodes().to$().removeClass('locked');
            socket.emit('unlock', rowID);
        }
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I think you know, when you're connected, you're keeping the data up-to-date, but if you have a momentary disconnect and then reconnect, you might have missed some data updates.

There are a number of possible strategies for dealing with this.

1. **Brute-force.**  Upon a reconnect, get a fresh copy of all the data as if the device had just been turned on.  Less efficient, but easy to implement.
2. **Transaction ID or Transaction Time.**  Each time the server sends an update, it sends either a transaction ID or a transaction server time with that update.  The client then keeps track of the last transaction ID or transaction time that it received.  When it does a reconnect, it sends an initial message with the last transaction ID or transaction time asking for any updates that have happened since that last transaction.  The server can then look through its database to see if there are any newer transactions and, if so, send them to that client.  This requires keep track of transactions at your database.  It is common that the server can possibly return a "transaction id not supported" type of response which then forces the client back to a brute-force update from scratch.  This is a back-stop in case a database rebuild or server crash causes older transaction values to get lost.
3. **True Synchronization.**  The client reconnects and then does a true synchronization with the server where the client essentially says "this is what I have, do you have anything newer".  In the interest of efficiency, many synchronization systems solve this problem by implementing the transaction id described in option 2, but there are certainly many other ways to do synchronization.  True synchronization is more useful if the client might also be changing the data while it was disconnected.

As a simplifying way of implementing option 2, if your database does not already support the notion of journaled transactions, then some servers will implement a transaction log in memory where it keeps track of the last N hours of transactions.  As long as the server stays up and a disconnect doesn't last longer than N hours, then a request for new data can be satisfied from the in memory transaction log (which is efficient).  If the server restarts or the client has been gone longer than N hours, then the client is just forced to do a brute-force update, the same as the client would have done if it was powered off and then powered back on (losing all prior knowledge of the data).

Of course, if there are multiple users of the database, then the transaction log has to be implemented by the database itself in order to make sure it includes all possible transactions.